# JQuery Error after test validation of components , form post

Tags: jquery, validation

If I click to the button, I verify if component is empty and I show an error.

As this :

```
 $("#btnEnvoyer").click(function () {
    effacerAnomalie("erreurs");
    var ano = 0;
    if ($("input[name=prenom]").val() == "") {
        showAnomalie('erreurs', "<%=ReferenceMessages.CONTACT_SAISIE_PRENOM%>");
        ano++;
    }

    if ($("input[name=nom]").val() == "") {
        showErros('erreurs', "<%=ReferenceMessages.CONTACT_SAISIE_NOM%>");
        ano++;
    }
});
```

after I test if I've an errors with :

```
  if ( ano < 1 ) { 
    // continue for submit button
  } else {
   // do nothing and the errors messages must be kept
  }
```

My bug is when I've an errors (ano >= 1) , My form submit (post) and clean the errors messages.

I don't know why.

Comment: Is `btnEnvoyer` a submit button? and are you checking for validation inside the same click event only?

Comment: Try to show the whole code.

Comment: the code of button is :
`<button id="btnEnvoyer">Envoyer</button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try something like this:

```
$("#btnEnvoyer").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    effacerAnomalie("erreurs");
    var ano = 0;
    if ($("input[name=prenom]").val() == "") {
        showAnomalie('erreurs', "<%=ReferenceMessages.CONTACT_SAISIE_PRENOM%>");
        ano++;
    }

    if ($("input[name=nom]").val() == "") {
        showErros('erreurs', "<%=ReferenceMessages.CONTACT_SAISIE_NOM%>");
        ano++;
    }

    if ( ano < 1 ) { 
      $("yourForm").submit();
    } else {
      // do nothing and the errors messages must be kept
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank's rayaner, i've add `return false;` in `else` and it works